# Docker, Python and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, docker

I'm trying to deploy a Python app with docker container.
I developed my app on Windows and Raspberry Pi 3B, that's why I use Python 2.7.16.

I build my Dockerfile as :

```
FROM python:2.7.16

# Set workspace
WORKDIR /app

# Install python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt 


# Copy local files
COPY . .

RUN ['python', 'main.py']
```

and my requirements as (coming from "pip freeze > requirements.txt" into my virtualenv):

```
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
colorzero==1.1
dnspython==1.16.0
fake-useragent==0.1.11
gpiozero==1.5.1
idna==2.10
numpy==1.16.6
pandas==0.24.2
pymongo==3.11.0
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.24.0
selenium==3.141.0
six==1.15.0
urllib3==1.25.10
```

Unfortunately, I got an error : "Python version >= 3.6 required" while downloading pandas==0.24.2.

It just seems strange because I already launch this python app using a virtualenv and the bash with this config.

Can you help me?

PS : I launch my project with: "sudo docker build -t test ."

Answer (score 0):

Use `FROM python:3.7` in your Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

This is because numpy doesn't support python 2 from version 1.17.0 onwards.

I fixed this by locking numpy to 1.16.6 and installing pandas separately after as pip didn't seem to be able to resolve the versions.

Pandas (currently) only requires numpy >= 1.12.0 so you should be alright for a while.

Comment: Has that worked for you on Pi 3? I tried on Pi 3B+ and I got only as far as getting Python3 working inside docker container but not numpy, even older version 1.14.